# Why is jest unit test broken?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

My reactjs component called Alerts sorts json-data by date/name, the component is working but not the unit test it breaks in a utilityfunction, this is the issue.

Part of the Alertscomponent uses a part of a utility function called createAlertsWithName. All it does is 'merging' 2 arrays into 1(because the alerts array does not contain a name and I need this to sort) :

```
export const createAlertsWithName = (alerts,applicants) =>{
    return alerts.map(a =>({
      ...a,
      name:(a.applicants
        .map(id =>getApplicantByid(id,applicants))
        .find(applicant => applicant.isPrimaryApplicant) ||{lastName:''}).lastName
    }))
  }
```

When I run 'npm test' I get the following error message:

```
Alerts › should render sorted data

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'isPrimaryApplicant' of undefined

       6 |       name:(a.applicants
       7 |         .map(id =>getApplicantByid(id,applicants))
    >  8 |         .find(applicant => applicant.isPrimaryApplicant) ||{lastName:''}).lastName
         |                                      ^
       9 |     }))
      10 |   }
      11 | 

      at isPrimaryApplicant (src/utility.js:8:38)
          at Array.find (<anonymous>)
      at find (src/utility.js:8:10)
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at map (src/utility.js:4:19)
      at createAlertsWithName (src/utility.js:17:12)
      at Alerts.render (src/Alerts.js:12:11)
```

This seems strange because I checked the 'name' property without the find-statement like this:

```
 name:(a.applicants
    .map(id =>getApplicantByid(id,applicants))
```

The output would be:

```
applicants: (2) ["000001262", "000001263"]
assignedDateTime: "2018-10-25T09:25:00Z"
createdDateTime: "2019-10-24T09:25:00Z"
dueDateTime: "2019-10-25T09:25:00Z"
id: "19d0da63-dfd0-4c00-a13a-cc822fc81297"
name: (2) [{…}, {…}]
subject: "What a nice day"
submissionId: "SUB200620150004197"
__proto__: Object
1:
applicants: ["000001201"]
assignedDateTime: "2018-10-25T09:25:00Z"
createdDateTime: "2018-10-24T09:25:00Z"
dueDateTime: "2018-10-25T09:25:00Z"
id: "19d0da63-dfd0-4c00-a13a-cc822fc81201"
name: [{…}]
subject: "Hello"
submissionId: "SUB200620150004201"
```

And it does not return an undefined 'name' as far as I can see. So why do I get the 'Cannot read property 'isPrimaryApplicant' of undefined' error ?

Comment: What is the output when you run it without the find statement?

Comment: What does the test data look like? Does it match what is used when the component works outside the test?

Comment: output see above

Comment: I added a link to github

Comment: has it solved the problem https://github.com/dimitri-a/error_in_test/commit/acad7b35758ff885f86e47e03fd71cee6b992d60 or it's still relevant?

Comment: Not solved yet @YevheniiHerasymchuk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ids(?) in `peopleMock.alerts[X].applicants` don't match any of the ids in `peopleMock.applicants[X].id`. This causes `getApplicantByid` to return `undefined` causing `applicant.isPrimaryApplicant` to be `undefined`. If you update the ids in `peopleMock.alerts[X].applicants` to the ids in `peopleMock.applicants[X].id`, the test runs. I'm not sure if the output is what you expect though. You'll probably want to update the `createAlertsWithName` function to handle the `undefined` in a reasonable way.

Maybe something like:

```
.find(applicant => applicant && applicant.isPrimaryApplicant) || 
  {
    lastName: ""
  }
```

Comment: How can i handle the undefined in this situation?